Task AzureAppServiceSetting@1: Application Settings object is not a valid JSON while deploying with YAML file from Azure Devops
I am trying to deploy an environment variable for the standard logic application with the YAML file using the AzureApServiceSettings@1 task.
One of the values has a JSON value.
[{"company_id":"TEST","id":"TEST","url_basic":"https://www.google.com/"}]
      [
        {
        "name":"Connection",
        "value": "$(Connection)",
        "slotSetting":false
        },
      ]

When I deploy those settings I am getting the error "Application Settings object is not a valid JSON"

I have tried a lot of options but none of them succeeded to deploy.
I tried to deploy with single quotes.  Without the square or braces
brackets.
Tried to escape the double quotes with a backslash, that
does also not the trick.

I run out of options and hope that one of you can help me to find the right way to deploy.

You need to escape the quotation marks in your JSON:
variables:
  - name: Connection
    value: '[{\"company_id\":\"TEST\",\"id\":\"TEST\",\"url_basic\":\"https://www.google.com/\"}]'

Test YAML pipeline:

Deployment log:

Result:


Thank you for your time and explanation. My bad, I forgot to put the single quote before the value of the variable and at the end of it. What a shame for me :) Thank you very much.
