convertJson doesn't escape values from variables when using macro syntax?
Consider the following Azure yaml pipeline and template that uses the convertToJson function to convert an object parameter to a json string:
parameters:
  - name: foo
    type: string
    default: 'b"ar'

trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  - name: foo
    value: 'b"ar'

steps:
  - checkout: none
  - template: /pipelines/steps/set-settings.yaml
    parameters:
      settings:
        fooLiteral: 'b"ar'
        fooParameter: ${{ parameters.foo }}
        fooCompiledVariable: ${{ variables.foo }}
        fooRuntimeVariable: $(foo)

Template /pipelines/steps/set-settings.yaml:
parameters:
  - name: settings
    type: object

steps:
  - script: |
      echo $SETTINGS
    displayName: 'Display settings'
    env:
      SETTINGS: ${{ convertToJson(parameters.settings) }}

When running the pipeline, why do all values get properly escaped except fooRuntimeVariable?


This looks like a https://devops.stackexchange.com/ question.

@tevemadar I don't think so. Aren't pipelines "software tools commonly used by programmers", as mentioned in What topics can I ask about here?? There is even a CI/CD collective here on SO, which includes tags like azure-pipelines, github-actions, etc.

CI/CD is a shield that people wield to post DevOps questions here. "Colorful icon, it must be right".

@tevemadar CI/CD is related to DevOps, but it's not the same thing.

Test the same YAML sample and I can reproduce the same issue.
The root cause of the issue is that the macro variable($(foo)) is not expand when the expression: ConvertToJson executes.
When the ConvertToJson expression executes, fooRuntimeVariable will keep the value of $(foo) instead of expand the value to 'b"ar'.
So its actual conversion result:
{ "fooLiteral": "b\"ar", "fooParameter": "b\"ar", "fooCompiledVariable": "b\"ar", "fooRuntimeVariable": "$(foo)" }

After you print it in the script task, the $(foo) will expand to the value: 'b"ar'.
{ "fooLiteral": "b\"ar", "fooParameter": "b\"ar", "fooCompiledVariable": "b\"ar", "fooRuntimeVariable": "b"ar" }

To prove this, I added condition to the template to check the conversion result:
Here is my example:
Template YAML:
parameters:
  - name: settings
    type: object

steps:

- script: |
    echo $SETTINGS
  displayName: 'Display settings'
  condition: eq('${{ convertToJson(parameters.settings) }}', 'b"ar')
  env:
      SETTINGS: ${{ convertToJson(parameters.settings) }}

Main YAML:
parameters:
  - name: foo
    type: string
    default: b"ar

trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'Ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  - name: foo
    value: b"ar

steps:
  - checkout: none
  
  - template: test.yml
    parameters:
      settings:
        fooLiteral: b"ar
        fooParameter: ${{ parameters.foo }}
        fooCompiledVariable: ${{ variables.foo }}
        fooRuntimeVariable: $(foo)

When we run the Pipeline, the Display settings task will skip. Then we can check the condition result: it will show the $(foo) for the fooRuntimeVariable.

To sum up, when we use ConvertToJson Expression, I suggest that we can use compile time expressions (${{xxx}}) to use variables.

Thanks Kevin for the detailed explanation, as usual - it makes perfect sense. I was trying to use convertToJson to generate application settings, as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79061480/task-azureappservicesetting1-application-settings-object-is-not-a-valid-json-w . My idea was to generate the json string dynamically, maybe even using variables from variable groups. But unfortunately this approach doesn't work as I expected.

PS: using the condition to check the generated expression is a cool trick, I need to remember that :-)

@RuiJarimba Glad to know it can help you. Have a nice day!
